# center and put a larger text area in Boostrap 4

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and have some issues:

1. Center the input-fiels (inline)
2. space between these inputs
3. add a larg textarea under the input-fiels

**This is what it looks like currently:**

[image]

**Here is my HTML code:**

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/50631/pexels-photo-50631.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-bridge-buildings-50631.jpg&fm=jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: white;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25%;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5em;
}

hr {
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solidrgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

input.transparent-input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: white;
}


/* Chrome, Firefox, Opera*/

 :-ms-input-placeholder.form-control {
  color: white;
}


/* Internet Explorer*/

.form-control::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}


/* Microsoft Edge */

.no-padding {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Zenuni Company</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="content">
          <h1>Contact Page</h1>
          <h3>Contact Us</h3>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
          </div>
        </form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Where is the textarea? How about the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

the first one is using grid system, this will work in this way:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second way that i think will fit better, I'm find this way more helpful when talking about responsive center.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">.col-md-6 .offset-md-3</div>
</div>
```

Hope i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your code and added to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3fowzdq/63/)

your form should be like this to achieve center inputs with margins :

```
     <form class="form-inline justify-content-center"> 
      <div class="form-group space-right">
       <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group space-right">
       <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname"  required>                   
      </div>         
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default  my-2 my-sm-0">Send invitation</button>             
     </form>
```

with this line of css :

```
    .space-right {margin-right:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `justify-content-center` for the row because `col-12` takes the whole row.

Instead of `form-inline`, use two `form-row` classes inside the form - one for the two inputs and the other for the button. And use a `col` for each of the inputs should you like to have them side by side on all kinds of devices. Otherwise, use `col-*` classes as you normally would, for instance, use `col-12 col-sm-6` so that they takes the whole width of its parent on mobile but half on other devices. And then use a `col` class for the button.

> You may also swap .row for .form-row, a variation of our standard grid row that overrides the default column gutters for tighter and more compact layouts. - [Bootstrap-4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row)

Restrict the width of the form only. In order to do so, use custom CSS as you have done so. If you do so, use `mx-auto` for the form to center it horizontally inside its container.

Should you like to have the button in the center of its parent, use `text-center` for its parent.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBWXME

---

One more thing, I guess you have used `align-items-center` to align all the content vertically in the center.  If so, use `h-100` for all the parents of the `container`. Otherwise, `align-items-center` won't work.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/50631/pexels-photo-50631.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=aerial-bridge-buildings-50631.jpg&fm=jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: white;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5em;
}

hr {
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solidrgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

input.transparent-input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: white;
}


/* Chrome, Firefox, Opera*/

:-ms-input-placeholder.form-control {
  color: white;
}


/* Internet Explorer*/

.form-control::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}



.mw-500px {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="content">
        <h1>Contact Page</h1>
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <form class="mw-500px mx-auto">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col form-group">
            <input class="form-control transparent-input" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Vorname" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row ">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              Send invitation</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Your input fields are not centered because they're not part of your `#content` element. If you move the first `</div>` tag after `<div id="content">` below your submit button, that should take care of that issue.
2. I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for in terms of space between your input fields. You could just use the `</br>` tag to make a space, but that will probably be a little ugly. I'd recommend going into your CSS code, selecting `.form-inline` and messing around with the padding until you're satisfied with how it looks
3. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, maybe I could help if you sketched a mock-up of what you're thinking of.

Hope this is useful!

Comment: You should not use `br` tag for that purpose. Use `CSS` margin or padding properties. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br